# Grouping trees and graphs with nodes

Tags: nodes, scoping, qtree

I would like to draw a tree as in the picture:

Could you help me please?
[image]

What I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{trees} % this is to allow the fork right path
\usetikzlibrary{scopes}

\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[grow'=right,level distance= 4.5cm,sibling distance=5pt]
\tikzset{edge from parent/.style={thick, draw, edge from parent fork right},every tree node/.style={draw,minimum width=3cm,text width=3cm,align=center}}

\Tree 
        [.\node [name=CG,xshift=-5cm,yshift=0cm,draw,minimum width=4cm,text width=4cm,align=center]{\textbf{Création de la géométrie}} ;
        [.\node [xshift=-4.5cm]{Fichier CAO} ; ]
        [.\node [xshift=-4.5cm]{Points (x,y,z)} ; ]
        [.\node [xshift=-4.5cm]{Fonction f(x,y,z)} ; ]
    ]

    \begin{scope}[yshift=-1.5cm,grow'=right]

\Tree
    [.\node [yshift=-0.2cm,below of=CG,draw,minimum width=4cm,text width=4cm,align=center] (GL) {\textbf{Génération des limites}};
        [.\node [xshift=-4cm,yshift=-1.2cm,draw,minimum width=4cm,text width= 4cm] {Plan de symétrie} ; ]
        [.\node [xshift=-4cm,yshift=-1.4cm,draw,minimum width=4cm,text width= 4cm]{Bords d'E/S} ; ]
        [.\node [xshift=-4cm,yshift=-1.6cm,draw,minimum width=4cm,text width= 4cm]{Bords périodiques} ; ]
        [.\node [xshift=-4cm,yshift=-1.8cm,draw,minimum width=4cm,text width= 4cm]{Bords solides} ; ]
    ] 
\end{scope}

 \begin{scope}[yshift=-3.2cm,grow'=right]

 \Tree
         [.\node [yshift=-0.8cm,below of=GL,draw,minimum width=4cm,text width=4cm,align=center] (GM){\textbf{Génération de maillage} } ;
        [.\node [xshift=-4cm,yshift=-2.4cm,draw,minimum width=4cm,text width= 4cm] (ST) {Structuré}; ]
        [.\node [xshift=-4cm,yshift=-3cm,draw,minimum width=4cm,text width= 4cm] {Non-structuré} ; ]
        [.\node [xshift=-4cm,yshift=-3.4cm,draw,minimum width=4cm,text width= 4cm] {hybride}; ]
    ]
    \end{scope}

 \begin{scope}[yshift=-5.6cm,grow'=right]

    \Tree
         [.\node [yshift=-0.8cm,below of=GL,draw,minimum width=4cm,text width=4cm,align=center] (AM){\textbf{Adaptation de maillage} } ;
        [.\node [xshift=-4cm,yshift=-2.8cm,draw,minimum width=6cm,text width= 6cm] (ST) {Adaptation  de la géométrie}; ]
        [.\node [xshift=-4cm,yshift=-3cm,draw,minimum width=6cm,text width= 6cm] {Adaptation de la couche limite} ; ]
        [.\node [xshift=-4cm,yshift=-3.2cm,draw,minimum width=6cm,text width= 6cm] {réglage de l'écoulement}; ]
    ]
    \end{scope}

 \draw[semithick,->] (CG)--(GL);
 \draw[semithick,->] (GL)--(GM);
 \draw[semithick,->] (GM)--(AM);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I still have this little job

[image]

Comment: Starting point: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/trees/